# Обучение созданию серверной части приложения

Tags: php, сервер, книги

Какие знания необходимы для работы в серверной части?
Полезную и простую литературу, можно ссылку на источники, примеры.
Верстка поднадоела =)

Comment: Исключительно те, которые требуется конкретно вам, в данный конкретный момент. "Святой истины" в выборе инструментов нет и не будет никогда.

Answer (score 1):

[Тут](http://phpfaq.ru/start) общая информация о том, как настроить `php` на локальной машине и ссылки на самоучители.

Comment: Не не ты не понял ,у меня уже все стоит XAMPP настроенный ,я бы хотел чтобы было как XML и JSON использовать,Ajax примеры,с серверной стороны

Answer (score 0):

[вот](http://www.books.ru/books/ajax-dlya-professionalov-477695/) неплохая книга по аяксу с примерами